# Select the different value from two columns from two tables mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have two table for example car and repair.
In both tables I have the column "licensePlate".
In the table `cars` I have the values: 0000 0001 0002 0003
In the table `repair` I have the values: 0000 0002 0003.
How can I extract only the value 0001 that is in the table `cars` but not in `repair`?
I think I don't use the correct "operator" or something like that:

```
select car.licensePlate
from car, repair
where car.licensePlate (something) reparir.licensePlate;
```

Comment: look into nested queries and IN and NOT IN, that would help you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use `NOT EXISTS` or `LEFT JOIN`, as in:

```
select c.licensePlate
from car c
where not exists (select 1 from repair r where c.licensePlate = r.licensePlate;
```

You specifically should *not* use `NOT IN`, because it has strange semantics (that is, acts weird) if the subquery returns a `NULL` value on *any* row.  When this occurs, then the outer query will return no rows as all.

For this reason, I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN` with subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not in` operator:

```
SELECT licensePlate
FROM   car
WHERE  licensePlate NOT IN (SELECT licensePlate
                            FROM   repair)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mureinik!

Answer (score 0):

Using the NOT IN operator should solve your problem. How it would work is:

SELECT CAR.LICENSEPLATE FROM CAR
WHERE CAR.LICNESEPLATE NOT IN (SELECT REPAIR.LICENSEPLATE FROM REPAIR)

When this query would be executed it would be read as:
SELECT CAR.LICENSEPLATE FROM CAR
WHERE CAR.LICNESEPLATE NOT IN (0000,0002,0003)

This is because in any query consisting of sub-query the sub-query is executed first, in this case which is SELECT REPAIR.LICENSEPLATE FROM REPAIR, and the result of the sub-query is passed on to the main query.  Which sums up to the query mentioned just above.

Hope it helps. Cheers!